# Is there a more elegant way to re-run a function after exception and fix?

Tags: python

In the situation of a function or a piece of code that fails to complete, we can fix the issue and re-run what we intended to do. Take a look at the example below.

```
try:
    increment_value(key)   # try to do something
except:                    # but it doesn't work (key doesn't exist)
    create_key(key)        # because something else needs to be done first
    increment_value(key)   # now we can do what we wanted to do from the start
```

It just doesn't feel good repeating oneself and I'm curious if there's a more elegant way of accomplishing this. I suppose this is a general Python question.

Comment: For one thing, never use [bare `except:`](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/). But without knowing more about what exactly goes wrong, we can't tell you what a [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl) solution looks like.

Comment: The example I provided is an EAFP way of doing it. I'm just asking if there's a more clever and DRY way to re-run after handling the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a structure like this could be used:

```
while True:
    try:
        increment_value(key)
    except:
        create_key(key)
    else:
        break
```

But I am not sure if it is better than the code snippet you proposed.

It does not have repetition, but is longer, and possibly harder to understand.

Another way could be the LBLY solution as suggested by jonrsharpe in a comment:

```
if not key_exists(key):
    create_key(key)
increment_value(key)
```

But I assume you *do not* want such a solution, but a EAFP approach.

Still, I wanted to add it here for sake of completeness.